# NLP : What are some common verbs surrounding organization names in text

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, nltk

I am trying to come up with some rules to detect named entities, specifically company or organization names in text. I think it makes sense to focus on verbs. There are a lot of `POS Taggers` that can easily detect proper nouns. I personally like `StanfordPOSTagger`. Now, once i have the proper noun, i know that it is a named entity. However, to be certain that it is the name of a company, i need to come up with rules and possibly `Gazetteers`

I was thinking of focusing on verbs. Is there a set of common verbs that occur frequently around company names?

I could create an annotated corpus and explicitly train a Machine Learning classifier to predict such verbs, but that is a LOT of work. It would be great if someone has already done some research on this.

Additionally, can some other `POS` tags give clues? Not just verbs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330227/free-tagged-corpus-for-named-entity-recognition

Comment: thanks Emre, but i want to build my own rules

Comment: That's what tagged corpuses are for. How are you going to know if your algorithm works without something to train on and test against?

Comment: oh, so you mean that look at the verbs around `ORG` tags for example. Now there can be a problem as i am now relying on the fact that the corpus has been tagged perfectly. What if i want to create `ORG` tags from scratch? POS tags can be my starting point. The reason i want to do this is that sometime StanfordNLP tools do not tag entities as expected